# Cronjob not working. Executable works, output is logged

Tags: python-3.x, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I am running apython script in a shell script, but now fallen back to running the python script directly from the crontab. All commands I put in crontab work when run in the terminal.

Also made sure my daemon is running, that I can see my job in `/var/spool/cron`, that there is an empty `/usr/lib/cron/cron.deny` file and no `cron.allow` file.

The path used in crontab does contain the path to python3 (`/usr/bin`) and I have tried different ways of writing the fact that I want to run it every minute: `*`, `*/1`.

Here's the cronjob:

```
*/1 * * * *  /usr/bin/python3 /home/me/Desktop/path/to/script.py >> ~/loggg
```

I scattered print statements in my python script and only a few surface in `loggg`, so im guessing it is something in the script, but I made sure that my home environment and python3 has all the right pip packages called. Actually I know the script goes through the import phases as I get a print statement after those.

One thing possibly is I used pip package `wget` within the script calling on an API. I know the call works when not a cronjob, but maybe that is what is messing up the job ?

Comment: Append `2>&1` to additionally log errors. It's probably trying to tell you what's wrong

Comment: @JC : I can not see in your question any description of what would not be working.

Comment: This scenario is almost always due to the environment.  Cron uses a limited env and therefore if you're calling functions which exist outside of /usr/bin you need to be explicit for cron to find them.  I wonder if your wget package contains the full path to wget by default.  Try replacing it with a bash callout with an explicit path.